# Is there a way to update a record after it's been created?

Tags: google-app-maker

I'm trying to update the id (not pk) of a record `onAfterCreate` in auto save mode. The `createContractNum_SOW()` is a server script that returns a number. I have also tried using

```
app.datasources.MyDatasource.item.MyField = 'My new value';
```

but that does not work either.

Is there something that I am missing?

```
if (contract_type === "Statement of Work"){
    var next_id = createContractNum_SOW();
    record.contract_num = next_id;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to save the record after you modify it.

Since the datasource events are server side you can do that with `app.saveRecords([record]);`